# Calling a specific action in a form tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an action vote_for in my question controller.

what is the helper that enbales me to call this action from a view?
i tried :

```
vote_for_question_path(@question)
```

but this didn't work. ?

Comment: Have you defined it in your `routes.rb` file?

Comment: nope.. but i have added resources:questions

Comment: should i add a route for this specific action?

Comment: What doesn't work? Are you receiving an error?

Comment: Try adding a [collection route](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions) to your resource route. I've posted an answer below that lays out step-by-step instructions for doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've already defined resourceful routes for the `Question` resource, you should start by adding a [member route](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions) on your existing resource route:

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :questions do
  member do
    get 'vote_for'
  end
end
```

This will create the following route:

```
vote_for_question GET    /questions/:id/vote_for(.:format)    questions#vote_for
```

Next, create a controller action for the resulting route:

```
# app/controllers/questions_controller.rb
def vote_for
  # logic goes here
end
```

Finally, in your view, you can construct a link to the route by passing the collection path to the `link_to` helper:

```
<%= link_to "Vote", vote_for_question_path(@question) %>
```

**UPDATE**:

If you'd rather represent the link as an HTML button than an `<a>` tag (as the OP is proposing in the comments to this answer), you can use the [`button_to` form helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to) as follows:

```
<%= button_to "Vote", vote_for_question_path(@question), method: "get" %>
```

Note that, because you're replacing the link with a button, you should ensure that you're passing the correct HTTP submission method (which is `GET` in this instance) as an argument.

Comment: i am using form_tag instead of link_to, is that correct? it is because i am using a button.

Comment: You shouldn't need to use `form_tag`. I've updated my answer to demonstrate how this could be accomplished using the `button_to` form helper.

Comment: thanks! well i have this code now  in html :    <a class="btn btn-default btn-lg" href="questions/..."><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span> <a> , how can i replace it with a link_to?

Comment: i want to replace it with link_to to use the helper vote_for_question_path, instead of href="/questions/vote_for/@question.id . how can i do this?

Comment: You're asking a lot of different question here. Hopefully this resolves them. If so, please consider upvoting my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The path helpers only come when you define them in your `routes.rb` as a named route.  So if you want a named non-RESTful route (which you do), you should add to your routes file:

```
get 'vote_for_question/:id', to: 'question#vote_for', as: 'vote_for_question'
```

And then you can call `vote_for_question_path(@question.id)` in your views and it will generate e.g. `/vote_for_question/1`.

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#generating-paths-and-urls-from-code for more on this.